# Testcafe get skipped tests in embedding-utils.js

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to add some personal static analysis to my testcafe tests according to different features I am testing. I found there is `getTypeScriptTestList` in the following API, https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/fcd93e8dbee76ea70786ee3aee4fb35990260e2a/src/embedding-utils.js#L66 (I am using Typescript), and I can get list of the tests with very basic info without running all the tests, however, there seems no information getting the skipped tests, wondering if I miss anything or if there is another better way?

I also had a look into https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-static-analyser which is cool, but I hope to do something simpler and hopefully from testcafe's API.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not supported at present.

Comment: Thanks for your help, may I propose a feature request in github?

Comment: For further discussion and updates, please refer to the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6238 thread in the TestCafe GitHub repository.

Comment: I've encountered another issue, there is one test file I cannot parse, and it always throw error `TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value`
and it seems to be happening in:
`fileContent = await promisified_functions_1.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');`

While this one test file has no difference from other tests, wondering if you know what might cause it?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to determine the cause of the issue from based on this information. I suggest you create an issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository ( https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md ). Please also add your sample code where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check if I can post the code, and hopefully I can figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone searches this issue, it's fixed now, it can get skipped tests in embedding-utils.js